# How variables are shared between two process when the fork is involved

Tags: c, linux, fork

```
/*  In alarm.c, the first function, ding, simulates an alarm clock.  */

#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int alarm_fired = 0;

void ding(int sig)
{
    alarm_fired = 1;
}

/*  In main, we tell the child process to wait for five seconds
    before sending a SIGALRM signal to its parent.  */

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;

    printf("alarm application starting\n");

    pid = fork();
    switch(pid) {
    case -1:
      /* Failure */
      perror("fork failed");
      exit(1);
    case 0:
      /* child */
        sleep(5);
        printf("getppid: %d\n", getppid());
        kill(getppid(), SIGALRM);
        exit(0);
    }

/*  The parent process arranges to catch SIGALRM with a call to signal
    and then waits for the inevitable.  */

    printf("waiting for alarm to go off\n");
    (void) signal(SIGALRM, ding);

    printf("pid: %d\n", getpid());
    pause();
    if (alarm_fired)
        printf("Ding!\n");

    printf("done\n");
    exit(0);
}

I have run the above code under Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

> user@ubuntu:~/Documents/./alarm
> alarm application starting
> waiting for alarm to go off
> pid: 3055
> getppid: 3055
> Ding!
> done
```

I have read the following statement from a book.

> It’s important to be clear about the
>   difference between the fork system
>   call and the creation of new threads.
>   When a process executes a fork call, a
>   new copy of the process is created
>   with its own variables and its own
>   PID. This new process is scheduled
>   independently, and (in general)
>   executes almost independently of the
>   process that created it.

Question:
It seems to me that the variable alarm_fired is shared between the original process and the new created process.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, variables are not shared across a `fork()`.  In your code, the child process never touches `alarm_fired`. What the child does is send a signal to the parent.  That signal fires a signal handler in the parent process' context, setting the variable.

Comment: pause simply causes the program to suspend execution until a signal occur. When the second process sends the signal, the original process receives it and immediately call function ding that changes the value of alarm_fired. Is it true that the function ding intercepts the signal early than pause?

Comment: `ding()` doesn't intercept the signal, it's the signal handler. that means that the parent process will call it as a result of receiving the signal.  `pause()` returns after all signal processing has occurred, that means calling any handlers.

Answer (score 7):

No. Each process gets its own copy of the variable (and pretty much everything else). If you change the variable in one process, it is changed only in that process, not in both. Each process has its own address space.

Compare that with threads, where all threads share a single address space, so a change in a variable in one thread will be visible in all other threads (within that process).

From the Linux [`fork(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) manpage:

> fork()  creates  a  child  process  that differs from the parent process only in its PID and PPID, and in the fact that resource utilizations are set to 0.  File locks and pending signals are not inherited.

Comment: @pls see my comments under Javier.

Answer (score 2):

It is shared in the sense that immediately after the fork it has the same value in both processes. BUT when either writes to it the change is not propagated to the other process (that what different .

Also, see [copy on write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) for interesting stuff.

#### EDIT

> It seems that the new created process
> modified the variable alarm_fired
> which is then later seen by the old
> process

The child is **sending a signal** to the parent. The parent then executes the handler and **personally** sets `alarm_fired` to one. The child itself never touches that variable.

Comment: @pls see my comments under Javier.

Comment: @q0987 You can't know when the parent receives the signal (you don't even know which runs first after the fork). One thing is clear: `alarm_fired = 1;` is executed by the handler. The parent process is the only one executing the handler.